# How coordinated are the different factions in the Gaza Strip?

Tags: terrorism, hamas

Watching today a video on Reddit's combat footage of sweaty dudes in civilian clothes mounting some variations of quassam rockets, pointing what looks like Israel's general direction and firing, I asked myself how coordinated the different factions in the Gaza Strip really are?

Hamas is often chastised of [breaking ceasefire agreements](https://www.un.org/unispal/document/auto-insert-177937/), but really, how in control is Hamas of the [various groups](https://www.longwarjournal.org/archives/2021/06/analysis-17-palestinian-militant-factions-identified-in-recent-gaza-conflict.php)?

Comment: This question is somewhat unclear. What factions or groups are you referencing? Are you saying there are non-Hamas militants involved and fighting along with Hamas? Or is this speaking of different cells of Hamas militants?

Comment: @DavidS added a link. it's a bit old, from 2021, but can demonstrate the complexity of a ceasefire in case it will be successfully negotiated.

Comment: @DavidS You could ask the question from the other direction. How much power do senior Hamas figures actually have to in directing the Hamas fighters? Is there a command structure that passes down orders or is it more like individual groups each doing the own thing.

Answer (score 4):

Just based on the sources you linked, the answer seems to be there's no clear answer.

[Another (US DNI)](https://www.dni.gov/nctc/ftos/pij_fto.html) gives a similar take on one of the major 'competitors' of Hamas:

> PIJ sometimes operates in coordination with HAMAS, although the groups have had a tense relationship because PIJ occasionally disagrees with HAMAS’s strategy for confronting Israel.

FWTW, your FDD source discusses that the groups tried to establish some ‘Joint Operations Room’ but that didn't last long before it fizzled.